# Show all results of a row in the same page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to show all the games related to it's category, the Sql that I'm trying here only shows me the games related to the game 5, how can I show all the games automatically?

```
<?php
$varCategoria_GameData = "0";
if (isset($_GET["cat"])) {
 $varCategoria_GameData = $_GET["cat"];
}

$sql_categoria = "SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE intCategoria =
( SELECT intCategoria FROM jogos WHERE idGames = 5)";
$query_categoria = mysql_query($sql_categoria, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error()); 
$categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_categoria);



 ?>


<?php  do { ?> 
<?php echo '<h1>'.$categoria['idGames'].'</h1>'; ?>
 <?php } while ($categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_categoria)); ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM jogos` test this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are to remove "WHERE idGames = 5" from

```
$sql_categoria = "SELECT * FROM jogos";
```

The query ends with "WHERE idGames = 5" which actually means what it says.

Then you can extract the fields from $categoria in this way:

```
$categoria['name_of_field'];
```

**IN ITALIAN:**

Devi togliere "WHERE idGames = 5" e farla risultare così:

```
$sql_categoria = "SELECT * FROM jogos";
```

Quello chiede alla query è

"SELECT intCategoria FROM jogos WHERE idGames = 5";
SELEZIONA intCategoria DA jogos DOVE idGames è 5

Poi da $categoria puoi estrarre i campi in questo modo:

```
$categoria['nome_del_campo'];
```

Comment: Hi, Mr.Web, thank you for your answer, but how can I display all the games related to the category, I didn't understand how putting "SELECT * FROM jogos"; will display the games related to the category of the current game played

Comment: OK @MariangelaVidotto can you show me the table fields? What is the table made of?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jogos` (
`idGames` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`strNome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`intCategoria` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php     
    $sql_categoria = "SELECT * FROM jogos";
    $result_categoria = mysql_query($sql_categoria, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_categoria))
    {
        //Use $row with the index of the field you want to display, or directly with the column name between quote.
        echo "Result :".$row[0]."<br />";
    }
?>
```

Also, use MySQLi functions : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php

It is more safer to avoid SQL injection